# Path to HBase jars seems to be broken in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, hbase

I've used stack overflow a lot in the past and found it extremely helpful, but I find myself needing to ask my first quest:

I am working on a map reduce project that will use Hbase. I am developing on windows and using cygwin's shell to run Hbase. I have followed all the install steps for installing Hbase on windows, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

> cygpath: error converting
>   "c:\cygwin\usr\local\hbase-0.92.1/conf:/usr/local/jre7/lib/tools.jar:c:\cygwin\usr\local\hbase-0.92.1:c:\cygwin\usr\local\hbase-0.92.1/lib/*.jar"
>   - Unknown error -1

And then it reports that it can't find the main class for some necessary .jar files which I'm assuming has to do with cygpath not handling the paths to those jars correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cygpath is trying to convert your cygwin path to a windows path and is failing

Comment: that's what I figured but I have no idea how to fix it because I am not making the call to cygpath. Hbase seems to be trying to access it's jars and can't because of the windows-style path.